# How to make Libsodium Available to Rust on Windows (beginner's guide)?

Tags: windows, rust, libsodium

I can't find any clear answers to this.

I'm a beginning Rust programmer (read the book, wrote and compiled simple programs). Almost no knowledge of C/C++. The platform is Windows 7 64-bit. Rust stable (managed by Rustup) and I'd prefer the GNU ABI.

I'm compiling a git repository that requires libsodium, and compiling exits with an error that libsodium is not found.

Is there a step-by-step guide to installing libsodium for my Rust setup? The documentation that I've found assumes a bit too much about the knowledge of the reader.

I did manage to compile and "install" libsodium in MSYS2, but then Rust (which I can't see from inside MSYS2) still can't find it.

What is the better way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

When I try to build [sodiumoxide](https://github.com/dnaq/sodiumoxide), it fails because pkg-config cannot find libsodium. To install it, go [here](https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/) and download the latest version named `libsodium-x.x.x-mingw.tar.gz`, where `x.x.x` is the version number. Extract it using a tool such as 7-zip, and copy `libsodium-win64` (or win32 for 32-bit systems) to a place of your choice.

For pkg-config to find libsodium, you need to copy `libsodium.pc` from `libsodium-win64/lib/pkgconfig` (or win32) to somewhere pkg-config will look. To find where pkg-config looks, run this command:

`pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config`

Copy `libsodium.pc` to one of the directories listed. If no directories are listed, you must add a directory (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210210/pkg-config-path-environment-variable/373217#373217) answer). pkg-config should now be able to find libsodium, so you can build libraries that require it.